# ImportError: cannot import name 'NoReturn' PyTorch on MacOS Catalina

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, macos-catalina, torchvision

I'm having this weird problem in running torchvision in macOS Catalina. Here's the traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/xdriyad/PycharmProjects/Resnet/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from model import ResNet50
  File "/Users/xdriyad/PycharmProjects/Resnet/model.py", line 1, in <module>
    import torch
  File "/Users/xdriyad/PycharmProjects/Resnet/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/__init__.py", line 573, in <module>
    import torch.quantization
  File "/Users/xdriyad/PycharmProjects/Resnet/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/quantization/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .quantize_fx import *
  File "/Users/xdriyad/PycharmProjects/Resnet/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/quantization/quantize_fx.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .fx import Fuser  # noqa: F401
  File "/Users/xdriyad/PycharmProjects/Resnet/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/quantization/fx/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .quantize import Quantizer
  File "/Users/xdriyad/PycharmProjects/Resnet/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/quantization/fx/quantize.py", line 2, in <module>
    from torch._fx import (
  File "/Users/xdriyad/PycharmProjects/Resnet/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/_fx/__init__.py", line 89, in <module>
    from .symbolic_trace import symbolic_trace, Tracer
  File "/Users/xdriyad/PycharmProjects/Resnet/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/_fx/symbolic_trace.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .proxy import Proxy, _create_proxy, TracerBase
  File "/Users/xdriyad/PycharmProjects/Resnet/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/_fx/proxy.py", line 7, in <module>
    from typing import Tuple, Dict, Optional, Iterable, NoReturn, Any, Union, Callable
ImportError: cannot import name 'NoReturn'
```

Comment: what version of python are you using?

Comment: the python version is 3.6

Comment: I kind of solved it, moved to miniconda for macOS and with python 3.8.x, now it's working perfectly. I think it had to do with the python version.

Comment: At least you need Python 3.6.2 to solve this issue.